# Check is file exists, not just the URL

Tags: php

I've seen tutorials over the internet for this, but I cannot get it to work.

I've got this in a while loop, but it shouldn't matter:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
$image_url = $deviceimg.($row->Image);
if(!file_exists($image_url))
{}
else {
$image_url = 'images/android.png';
}
```

Basically, im my database, all the rows called Image are populated, but only some of them have an actual file.  What im trying to do is check to see if the image file actually exists on the server, if it doesn't use a default image (images/android.png)

No matter that I do, it will either replace ALL images with the default, or it will just use the URL in the database, regardless of if the file actually exists.

Comment: Please supply some debugging information, aka "What have you tried?". This will simply boil down to the path being incorrect, which can be easily found by doing `var_dump($image_url)` put before the `if`. What does `$deviceimg` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have a problem is because you have wrapped `$image_url` in single quotes when you pass it to `file_exists()`. This is checking whether there is a file file literally named `$image_url`, instead of using the contents of the variable.

Change

```
if (!file_exists('$image_url'))
```

to

```
if (!file_exists($image_url))
```

and it will work.

Comment: I've just updated my question.  Tried it with and without double quotes.  It still returns blank images for where the file doesn't exist, and the correct images where they do exist

Comment: Are you sure `images/android.png` exists? Call `file_exists()` on that as well...

Comment: If I swap the if statement around so the else statement is blank, it replaces ALL images with images/android.png.  If i get the properties of where the blank image is, its linking to the unique image for each database entry, which doesn't exist

Comment: Try replacing the whole lot with `while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { $image_url = (file_exists($deviceimg.$row->Image)) ? $deviceimg.$row->Image : 'images/android.png'; }` and see what happens

Comment: All images, regardless of if they exist or not are coming back as images/android.png.  If i echo $deviceimg.$row->Image into the image source, it shows the image if it exists.  If I echo images/android.png into the source it shows that image, so this confirms the files are definately there

Comment: Sorted.  Needed to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get it to identify if the file existed or not

Answer (score 1):

`'$image_url'` does not get parsed to the contents of the variable `$image_url`: it will stay the same string literal.

Remove the quotes. Only variables in double quotes (`"$image_url"`) will get parsed.

Comment: I've just updated my question.  Tried it with and without double quotes.  It still returns blank images for where the file doesn't exist, and the correct images where they do exist